# How to detect if Mac OS X is being run inside a Virtual Machine

Tags: macos, virtual-machine

I don't want my app to be run inside a virtual machine on Mac. How can I detect it from my Mac app. The solutions for Windows and Linux are pretty simple and discussed in details in other similar questions. I don't mind executing

`system_profiler` or `ioreg`

to find it out. But what to look for?  I am targeting Parallels, VMware Fusion and Virtual Box

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Searching for `VirtualBox`, `Oracle`, `VMware` and `Parallels` in the output of following command does the job very well:

```
ioreg -l | grep -e Manufacturer -e 'Vendor Name'
```