# Is there an API on mac-OSX to check if program is running inside VM

Tags: macos, virtual-machine, osx-yosemite

I want to programmatically determine on MAC-OSX, if my program is running inside a VM.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to detect if Mac OS X is being run inside a Virtual Machine](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28529633/how-to-detect-if-mac-os-x-is-being-run-inside-a-virtual-machine)

Comment: I wanted to rely on an API for this.