# detecting if my process is running on a virtual macos x instance and not on my local mac machine

Tags: macos, amazon-ec2

I m trying to identify if my launched process is running on a local mac machine(desktop/laptop) or a virtual macOS X instance like AWS EC2, Azure, MacStadium etc.

I have followed [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28529633/how-to-detect-if-mac-os-x-is-being-run-inside-a-virtual-machine) link which searched for its limited providers in the output, but I m not bound to any limited providers and looking for a general solution which is applicable to all the providers.

Is there some hardware/network/virtualization-related information that can be used to identify if the process is launched on a virtual MacOS instance?